# AngularJS "XMLHttpRequest cannot load..." errors on ng-include when using <script> templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates

Whenever I try and use a template in angular, I receive the error:

> HttpRequest cannot load https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?service=wise&passive=1209600&c…crc5kl5f5r3foguqzq-script.googleusercontent.com/dropdownInputTemplate.html. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://n-hs6zsnnha2qnez4bokwgxcrc5kl5f5r3foguqzq-script.googleusercontent.com' is therefore not allowed access.

I'm not trying to load templates from file, or from another URL. I have them in my markup as `<script>` templates as described [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache). The templates do work, they show up perfectly fine, but the console is spammed with errors.

Template:

```
<script id="textInputTemplate.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <div ng-if="column.editable" class="ui fluid input">
        <input class="editing" ng-model="colleague[column.name]" type="text">
    </div>
    <span ng-if="!column.editable">{{colleague[column.name]}}</span>            
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-include="'textInputTemplate.html'">

</div>
```

As I said previously, the templates work, but they spam the console with the above error. How do I fix this?

Comment: what's the dropdownInputTemplate.html?

Comment: That's just another template I have, I have a few hundred errors in the console. I must have copy/pasted one for a different input field.

Comment: you include textInputTemplate.html, why does it throw dropdownInputTemplate.html error? i think you can create a plunker